# Turn a binary tree array into a one-dimensional array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, recursion, bubble-sort

I'm attempting to program bubble sort recursively.
This is my code so far:

```
function recursive_bubble_sort(array) {
    if (array.length === 1) {
        return array;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
            var temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
            array[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }

    return [recursive_bubble_sort(array.splice(0, array.length - 1)), array[array.length -1]];
}
```

Technically it sorts the array but the return is not a one-dimensional array, instead it's in a reverse binary tree structure.

If the given array is `[ 8, 2, 5, 1 ]`,
the output would be `[ [ [ [ 1 ], 2 ], 5 ], 8 ]`.
How can I change the code so the output is like this: `[ 1, 2, 5, 8 ]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `return` statement

```js
return [recursive_bubble_sort(array.splice(0, array.length - 1)), array[array.length -1]];
```

However, since `recursive_bubble_sort` either returns a single element `recursive_bubble_sort` or an array (the other `return`), you need to handle both.

One easy way is to just use [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) - if you give it a single element, it adds it to a the array, if you give it an array, it adds all elements, instead. This ensures the result is always flat:

You can instead

```js
function recursive_bubble_sort(array) {
    if (array.length === 1) {
        return array[0];
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
            var temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
            array[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }

    return [].concat(recursive_bubble_sort(array.splice(0, array.length - 1)), array[array.length -1]);
}

console.log(recursive_bubble_sort([ 8, 2, 5, 1 ]))
```

Comment: Thank you, `concat()` is what I was looking for, I tried to use `push()` but it didn't help.

Comment: Not really needed to use `splice`. `slice` will do the job without side effects.

Comment: You could also do `return [...recursive_bubble_sort(array.slice(0, -1)), ...array.slice(-1)];`  I find this cleaner than `concat`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet [doesn't work](https://jsbin.com/nezetedowu/edit?js,console) because the first exit condition returns a simple item, and this would attempt to spread it. To succeed, the basic case should always wrap the value in an array but for me that's unnecessary.

Comment: Ah, I just copied the `return` from my own version, not noticing this change.  But that points to another problem here, which is that sorting a one-element array returns a scalar value, not an array.  I'll add a separate answer.

Comment: @ScottSauyet didn't consider this but you're right.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly different version, using destructuring instead of a temporary variable for the swap and the spread operator to build the output:

```js
const recursive_bubble_sort = (arr) => {
  if (arr.length < 2) {return arr}

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i ++) {
    if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
      [arr[i], arr[i + 1]] = [arr[i + 1], arr[i]]
    }
  }

  return [... recursive_bubble_sort (arr.slice(0, -1)), ... arr.slice(-1)]
}

console .log (recursive_bubble_sort ([8, 2, 5, 1]))
```

That last line could also be

```js
  return [... recursive_bubble_sort (arr.slice(0, -1)), arr[arr.length - 1]]
```

.  It's simply an aesthetic call.